# Query a MongoDB Server Using Express (Node.js project)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've created a route in a Node.js project to render all "logs" from a MongoDB database to a Web page:

```
   app.get('/api/logs', function (req, res) {
    Log.find( function (err, logs) {
     res.json(logs);
    });
   });
```

I want to modify this query to (1) limit the response to 10 logs and (2) display the logs in reverse chronological order (from most recent to least recent). If I try the below code, nothing will render to my page and my Node server gives the following error: **Error: sort() only takes 1 Argument**.

```
   app.get('/api/logs', function (req, res) {
    Log.find().limit(10).sort({$natural:-1}, function(err, logs){
     res.json(logs);
    });
   });
```

The above snippet DOES work if I type it directly into my Monog console as a single query: **Log.find().limit(10).sort({$natural:-1})** Is there a different way to write this to grab the information I want? Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: sort gets one object, you ma place its keys separated with comma

Comment: You should look into using something like Mongoose to help manage mongo. It'll make your life much easier.

Comment: [**$natural**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/#behavior) refers to the order of documents *"as they appear"* on disk ( citation in the link ), therefore is likely not what you want. A better indicator or "creation" is to create a "timestamp" field with the creation date, or just use the immutable `_id` field, contains a timestamp and sorts accordingly. `Log.find().sort({ "_id": -1 }).limit(10),function(err,logs) { ... })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly:

```
app.get('/api/logs', function (req, res) {
    Log.find().limit(10).sort(-fieldToSort).exec(function(err, logs){
        res.send(logs)
    })
   });
```

The -fieldToSort sorts the field in a descending order as you requested. fieldToSort is the field name you want to sort.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You can see more of this query methods [here](http://christekh.com/2015/07/24/popular-mongoose-query-methods-with-examples/)